# BPFDoor injection point and containment

Tags: malware, incident-response, cyber-warfare

How to determine BPFdoor entrypoint?I used following link to detect it on host https://blog.qualys.com/vulnerabilities-threat-research/2022/08/01/heres-a-simple-script-to-detect-the-stealthy-nation-state-bpfdoor but couldn't determine any specific entry point or C2 IP

Comment: Modify the script to echo out the lsof output if the if statement is true.